# Simple_form select input collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a select input for a simpleform with a collection. Is it possible to send three values through?

Something like this?

```
<option value="3925" value2='abc'>Aberdeen</option>
```

Where `value2` is the additional value i want sending?

```
<%= demo_distribution.input "sector", as: :select, collection: [['Aberdeen', 3925]], required: false%>
```

Comment: Well can you show the corresponding Rails code which generating these option values ? Your code will help us to help you fast.

Answer (score 0):

The `<option>` tag should be part of a `<select>` or similar element. It's possible to select multiple options in a `<select`> element but not to have multiple values in one `<option>` element.

Check this out for Rails select/option helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags